# file delimiter not working with awk code

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file which looks like this:

```
Name    Length  EffectiveLength TPM NumReads
ENST00000456328.2|ENSG00000223972.5|OTTHUMG00000000961.2|OTTHUMT00000362751.1|DDX11L1-202|DDX11L1|1657|lncRNA|  1657    1493.961    0.112690    3.673
ENST00000450305.2|ENSG00000223972.5|OTTHUMG00000000961.2|OTTHUMT00000002844.2|DDX11L1-201|DDX11L1|632|transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene|   632 468.996 0.000000    0.000
ENST00000488147.1|ENSG00000227232.5|OTTHUMG00000000958.1|OTTHUMT00000002839.1|WASH7P-201|WASH7P|1351|unprocessed_pseudogene|    1351    1187.961    9.176212    237.800
ENST00000619216.1|ENSG00000278267.1|-|-|MIR6859-1-201|MIR6859-1|68|miRNA|   68  69.000  0.000000    0.000
ENST00000473358.1|ENSG00000243485.5|OTTHUMG00000000959.2|OTTHUMT00000002840.1|MIR1302-2HG-202|MIR1302-2HG|712|lncRNA|   712 548.982 0.000000    0.000
ENST00000469289.1|ENSG00000243485.5|OTTHUMG00000000959.2|OTTHUMT00000002841.2|MIR1302-2HG-201|MIR1302-2HG|535|lncRNA|   535 372.012 0.000000    0.000
```

and I want the output as:

[image]

I tried, using AWK:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="\t" } { sub("\\..*", "", $1); print }'
```

and it prints the first id ENST. But when I change it to:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="\t" } { sub("\\..*", "", $5); print }'
```

it doesn't do anything.

So I tried

```
awk -F\| '{print $5"\t"$7"\t"$9}'
```

It works, but produces the length column twice and the output file loses the header.

Can someone help?

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: Downvoted for ignoring [the first comment above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/595008/file-delimiter-not-working-with-awk-code#comment1110341_595008) to post text, not an image. Without textual sample input/output we have nothing to test a potential solution against for a simple pass/fail result.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the first column of your `<TAB>`-separated file always has 9 elements (actually, "at least 5 elements" is enough), separated by vertical bars (`|`) (the ninth element being always empty in the sample you provided), and that your aim is to only pick the fifth element from it, you may use AWK's convenient `split` function:

```bsh
awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' \
  'NR > 1 { split($1, t, /\|/); $1 = t[5]; } 1' input_file |
  column -t -R 2,3,4,5
```

`column` from the [util-linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) package is then used to format the output as a table (`-t`), with the list of right-aligned columns given to the `-R` option as a comma-separated list.

If needed, you may force the conversion of appropriate fields to numbers to more closely match the output shown in your question. E.g. with `$5 = $5 + 0` you get `237.800` → `237.8` and `0.000` → `0`.

Alternatively, expanding on the `sub`stitute-based approach shown in your question, under the aforementioned assumptions—but with the requirement of *exactly* nine, possibly empty, vertical bar-separated elements in the first field—the AWK script may become (other things equal):

```c
NR > 1 { gsub(/^([^|]*\|){4,4}|(\|[^|]*){4,4}$/,"",$1); } 1
```

`gsub` is used in place of `sub` because we want to remove two matched substrings: the first four `|`-separated elements (note the `^` anchor) and the last four ones (note the `$` anchor).

Comment: isn't it `column -t -c 2,3,4,5` rather than `-R` ?

Comment: @Archemar Fixed the `-r` in the explanation paragraph, thanks for pointing me to that. I'm using `-R` to align columns to the right to match the image in the question. What would `-c` do? I think it wouldn't be meaningful with `-t`.

Answer (score 1):

The world is your oyster..

With `awk` if you split on `|` then all of your data is in the last field and your `Name` is in `$(NF-4)` so you can just .....

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==1{print }NR>1{print $(NF-4) $NF}' file | column -t -R 2,3,4,5

Name             Length  EffectiveLength       TPM  NumReads
DDX11L1-202        1657         1493.961  0.112690     3.673
DDX11L1-201         632          468.996  0.000000     0.000
WASH7P-201         1351         1187.961  9.176212   237.800
MIR6859-1-201        68           69.000  0.000000     0.000
MIR1302-2HG-202     712          548.982  0.000000     0.000
MIR1302-2HG-201     535          372.012  0.000000     0.000
```

You could then `split` `$NF` on `\t` to get your `0` formatting

```
awk -F'|' '
   NR==1{print }
   NR>1{split($(NF),vs,"\\t"); print $(NF-4), vs[2]+0, vs[3]+0, vs[4]+0, vs[5]+0}' file | 
   column -t -R 2,3,4,5

Name             Length  EffectiveLength      TPM  NumReads
DDX11L1-202        1657          1493.96  0.11269     3.673
DDX11L1-201         632          468.996        0         0
WASH7P-201         1351          1187.96  9.17621     237.8
MIR6859-1-201        68               69        0         0
MIR1302-2HG-202     712          548.982        0         0
MIR1302-2HG-201     535          372.012        0         0
```

Or if you have g`awk` then you could also use multiple delimiters `[|\t]`...

```
awk -F'[|\t]' '
   NR==1{print }
   NR>1{print $(NF-8), $(NF-3)+0, $(NF-2)+0, $(NF-1)+0, $NF+0}' file | 
   column -t -R 2,3,4,5

Name             Length  EffectiveLength      TPM  NumReads
DDX11L1-202        1657          1493.96  0.11269     3.673
DDX11L1-201         632          468.996        0         0
WASH7P-201         1351          1187.96  9.17621     237.8
MIR6859-1-201        68               69        0         0
MIR1302-2HG-202     712          548.982        0         0
MIR1302-2HG-201     535          372.012        0         0
```

Or you could leave `awk` out of it entirely and

```
cut -d '|' --output-delimiter=" " -f 5,9 file | column -t -R 2,3,4,5

Name             Length  EffectiveLength       TPM  NumReads
DDX11L1-202        1657         1493.961  0.112690     3.673
DDX11L1-201         632          468.996  0.000000     0.000
WASH7P-201         1351         1187.961  9.176212   237.800
MIR6859-1-201        68           69.000  0.000000     0.000
MIR1302-2HG-202     712          548.982  0.000000     0.000
MIR1302-2HG-201     535          372.012  0.000000     0.000
```