# delete specific rows from a tab separted file

Tags: awk, delete, tabs

I have a tab separated file, which has 6 columns, but some rows are not so:
[image]

There are many such lines in my file like the 7th. When I write

```
awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$5"\t"$6}' filename
```

it still gets retained. How do I get rid of such entries ?
Kindly help.

Comment: Please, don't post [screenshots of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, and contributors willing to help you will have to type-copy all example content when trying to reproduce your problem or improve your attempt. Instead, copy-and-paste the file with proper formatting.

Comment: You were asked not to post images when you posted [your last question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/595008/133219) too. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your attempt is that you are simply printing the first 6 columns of every line of your input file to the standard output. If there are less columns in any given line, `awk` interprets the missing ones as "empty", so the output of your 7th line should actually be something like

```
chr1 \t 290338 \t 290378 \t NS500455:80:HG7TMBGXB:$:13404:14651:1128 \t + \t \n
```

(spaces around `\t` added for readability; note the "empty" column at the end).

In order to filter out malformed lines based on column count, you can try

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NF==6' file.txt > output.txt
```

It will only print those lines that have 6 fields (=columns).

Comment: can you kindly write the full code?

Comment: @user1738234 Actually that is the full code. There is only one condition, `NF==6`, in the `awk` program. If the condition is true and there are 6 columns, the line will be printed. If not, the it will be omitted from the output. Note, that this assumes that the malformed input lines _really_ have a different number of column separators than required, and no "empty" columns (i.e. there must be no `... \t \t ...` without anything in between the tabs). If that is the case, you may want to look at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/599994/377345) on how to identify empty fields.

Comment: no what I mean is : awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$5"\t"$6}' | awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NF==6' file.txt

Comment: From your question, I assumed that you have an input file as shown, where alle columns are tab-separated, and want to filter out all lines that don't have 6 columns, and that the `awk '{print $1 ... $6}' filename` was your attempt at doing so. If that is the case, you can replace that command by my proposed command. If something else is to be done, you need to edit your question to clarify that.

Comment: awk '{-F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NF==6'}' file.txt
awk: cmd. line:1: {-Ft -v OFS=t NF==6}
awk: cmd. line:1:            ^ syntax error

Comment: @user1738234 Look at how I wrote it: There are _no_ curly braces.